# how to parse this hard json to dataframe in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

another question about this topic.

There are several questions and answer in this community about it:

1. [how to convert json to csv in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002058/how-to-convert-json-to-csv-in-python)
2. [Convert Json to CSV using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568649/convert-json-to-csv-using-python)
3. [Python convert JSON to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454216/python-convert-json-to-csv)
4. [Convert JSON to CSV with Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46350765/convert-json-to-csv-with-python-3)
5. It follows...

But I think in this case, it doesn't work for this hard json:

**MY JSON:**

```
    {
   "took":32,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":4,
      "successful":4,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":{
         "value":94,
         "relation":"eq"
      },
      "max_score":"None",
      "hits":[

      ]
   },
   "aggregations":{
      "hostname":{
         "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
         "sum_other_doc_count":0,
         "buckets":[
            {
               "key":"396",
               "doc_count":47,
               "process_name":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":16,
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "key":"accounts-daemon",
                        "doc_count":2,
                        "process_state":{
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                           "buckets":[
                              {
                                 "key":"sleeping",
                                 "doc_count":2,
                                 "process_pid":{
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                    "buckets":[
                                       {
                                          "key":1092,
                                          "doc_count":2,
                                          "process_ppid":{
                                             "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                             "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                             "buckets":[
                                                {
                                                   "key":1,
                                                   "doc_count":2,
                                                   "process_pgid":{
                                                      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                      "buckets":[
                                                         {
                                                            "key":1092,
                                                            "doc_count":2,
                                                            "process_cmdline":{
                                                               "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                               "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                               "buckets":[
                                                                  {
                                                                     "key":"/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon",
                                                                     "doc_count":2,
                                                                     "process_username":{
                                                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                                        "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                                        "buckets":[
                                                                           {
                                                                              "key":"root",
                                                                              "doc_count":2,
                                                                              "process_cwd":{
                                                                                 "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                                                 "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                                                 "buckets":[
                                                                                    {
                                                                                       "key":"/",
                                                                                       "doc_count":2,
                                                                                       "process_cpu_start_time":{
                                                                                          "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                                                          "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                                                          "buckets":[
                                                                                             {
                                                                                                "key":1570456346000,
                                                                                                "key_as_string":"2019-10-07T13:52:26.000Z",
                                                                                                "doc_count":2,
                                                                                                "process_fd_limit_hard":{
                                                                                                   "value":4096.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_fd_open":{
                                                                                                   "value":8.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_memory_size":{
                                                                                                   "value":281055232.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_memory_rss_bytes":{
                                                                                                   "value":6168576.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_memory_share":{
                                                                                                   "value":5464064.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_pct":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0005
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_fd_limit_soft":{
                                                                                                   "value":1024.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_system_ticks":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_user_ticks":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_norm_pct":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0005
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_ticks":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_value":{
                                                                                                   "value":18775.0
                                                                                                }
                                                                                             }
                                                                                          ]
                                                                                       }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                 ]
                                                                              }
                                                                           }
                                                                        ]
                                                                     }
                                                                  }
                                                               ]
                                                            }
                                                         }
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "key":"961",
               "doc_count":47,
               "process_name":{
                  "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                  "sum_other_doc_count":16,
                  "buckets":[
                     {
                        "key":"accounts-daemon",
                        "doc_count":2,
                        "process_state":{
                           "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                           "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                           "buckets":[
                              {
                                 "key":"sleeping",
                                 "doc_count":2,
                                 "process_pid":{
                                    "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                    "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                    "buckets":[
                                       {
                                          "key":1070,
                                          "doc_count":2,
                                          "process_ppid":{
                                             "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                             "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                             "buckets":[
                                                {
                                                   "key":1,
                                                   "doc_count":2,
                                                   "process_pgid":{
                                                      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                      "buckets":[
                                                         {
                                                            "key":1070,
                                                            "doc_count":2,
                                                            "process_cmdline":{
                                                               "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                               "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                               "buckets":[
                                                                  {
                                                                     "key":"/usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon",
                                                                     "doc_count":2,
                                                                     "process_username":{
                                                                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                                        "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                                        "buckets":[
                                                                           {
                                                                              "key":"root",
                                                                              "doc_count":2,
                                                                              "process_cwd":{
                                                                                 "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                                                 "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                                                 "buckets":[
                                                                                    {
                                                                                       "key":"/",
                                                                                       "doc_count":2,
                                                                                       "process_cpu_start_time":{
                                                                                          "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
                                                                                          "sum_other_doc_count":0,
                                                                                          "buckets":[
                                                                                             {
                                                                                                "key":1570450883000,
                                                                                                "key_as_string":"2019-10-07T12:21:23.000Z",
                                                                                                "doc_count":2,
                                                                                                "process_fd_limit_hard":{
                                                                                                   "value":4096.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_fd_open":{
                                                                                                   "value":8.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_memory_size":{
                                                                                                   "value":281153536.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_memory_rss_bytes":{
                                                                                                   "value":5992448.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_memory_share":{
                                                                                                   "value":5279744.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_pct":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_fd_limit_soft":{
                                                                                                   "value":1024.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_system_ticks":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_user_ticks":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_norm_pct":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_ticks":{
                                                                                                   "value":0.0
                                                                                                },
                                                                                                "process_cpu_total_value":{
                                                                                                   "value":13410.0
                                                                                                }
                                                                                             }
                                                                                          ]
                                                                                       }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                 ]
                                                                              }
                                                                           }
                                                                        ]
                                                                     }
                                                                  }
                                                               ]
                                                            }
                                                         }
                                                      ]
                                                   }
                                                }
                                             ]
                                          }
                                       }
                                    ]
                                 }
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

I have tried almost everything and I reached out to parse it with a horrible multiloop code, but I think there is an easier way to do this, but no post in this community has been aple to help me.

Could you help me to obtain something like this?:

**My result (incomplete):**

```
   hostname     process_name process_state  ...  process_username  process_cwd    process_cpu_start_time
0       396  accounts-daemon      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T13:52:26.000Z
1       396           iscsid      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T13:52:27.000Z
2       396           iscsid      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T13:52:28.000Z
3       396      ksoftirqd/0      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T13:52:28.000Z
4       396      kworker/0:1      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T13:52:28.000Z
..      ...              ...           ...  ...               ...          ...                       ...
25      961          polkitd      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T12:21:31.000Z
26      961        rcu_sched      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T12:21:31.000Z
27      961          systemd      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T12:20:24.000Z
28      961  systemd-journal      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T12:20:38.000Z
29      961  unattended-upgr      sleeping  ...              root            /  2019-10-07T12:21:26.000Z
```

I know it is not easy, so I'll appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## The idea

The main idea is to navigate down the structure of your JSON object.
To make the program readable, I came up with 2 functions, which perform
this navigation and append the keys along the descension path to a list
(the content of the current row).

## Functions to navigate down the JSON object

**Function 1:**

```
def dig(dct, path):
    ret = dct
    for step in path.split('.'):
        if step not in ret:
            print(f'**** No {step} element.')
            return None
        ret = ret[step]
        if isinstance(ret, list):
            ret = ret[0]
    return ret
```

This function "digs into" *dct* - a dictionary (a *JSON* object),
along the *path* (dot separated string).
An additional detail is that if the target sub-object (to which the function
descended) is a *list*, then there is additional "go down" step, namely the
function descends to the first element of this list.
The return value is the "final" sub-object, after all descends.

**Function 2:**

```
def dig2(dct, step, res, key='key'):
    dct = dig(dct, step + '.buckets')
    res.append(dct[key])
    return(dct)
```

Parameters:

- *dct* - the source dictionary,
- *step* - the first step of the path to descend,
- *res* - the result list, to which append the key after descend,
- *key* - the name of the key to read from the target sub-object.

This function speeds up the navigation down the source object. You specify only
the first *step* and this function descends one step deeper (to *buckets*).
Then *res* is appended with the *key* found at this level.

The return value is again the "final" sub-object, to be used to perform
further descends.

## Read the source JSON file

To read your JSON string, I saved it in a file and read as follows:

```
with open('input.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
```

## List of steps

The list of steps, to navigate down the source object is as follows:

```
steps = ['hostname', 'process_name', 'process_state', 'process_pid',
    'process_ppid', 'process_pgid', 'process_cmdline',
    'process_username', 'process_cwd', 'process_cpu_start_time']
```

This list is also the list of column names in the result DataFrame.

## Main program

```
tbl = []
for buck in dig(data, 'aggregations.hostname')['buckets']:
    res = [buck['key']]
    for step in steps[1:-1]:
        buck = dig2(buck, step, res)
    dig2(buck, steps[-1], res, 'key_as_string')
    tbl.append(res)
result = pd.DataFrame(tbl, columns=steps)
```

First we create *tbl* - an empty list, where data for subsequent rows
will be collected.

Then, *for buck in ...* operates on each *bucket* within *aggregations.hostname*.

The first element of the result for the current row is *key* from the current *bucket*.

After that, *for step in steps[1:-1]* digs into following steps, excluding the last,
and adds each *key* to the result list.

The last step of descending is outside this loop, because this time the key to
append is *key_as_string*, and finally *res* (data for the current row)
is added to *tbl*.

After the loop, the result DataFrame is created.

As the source JSON object included in your post contains only 2 buckets,
this DataFrame contains only 2 rows.